# Add custom File Upload attribute to admin user

Tags: adminhtml, custom-attributes, file-upload, admin-user

I want to add `Custom` tab below the `User Info` tab, in which I want add new custom field to upload images. 
How to achieve this?

Comment: What version of Magento you are using?